# SOAP API ERROR, Object reference not set to an instance of an object while trying to generate token in php

Tags: php, json, api, soap

I am integrating with a provider using soap response, i already made a call with generated token using soapUI application with given username and password. However, i want to achieve the generation of token using php

my code is

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.xxxxx.com/eSalesTest/webservice/xxx.asmx?wsdl", 
        array(
            "trace"      => 1,
            "exceptions" => 1,
            "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,
            "classmap" => array('timezone' => 'NIG')
            ));


$param2 = array(
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password,
);


$resulttoken = $client->getToken($param2);
$json = $resulttoken->getTokenResult;
$items = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($item);
```

After running the code, i got the error stdClass Object ( [getTokenResult] => stdClass Object ( [IsSuccessful] => [message] => Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ) ) . which actually shows that is succesful but token is not generated. Please help

Comment: what does var_dump($resulttoken); give you?

Comment: Still not working, im getting WARNING json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given on line number 18
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["getTokenResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["IsSuccessful"]=> bool(false) ["message"]=> string(53) "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." } }